# Airflow webservice server is not working

Tags: server, ssh, apache2, webserver

I have created a service file for an Airflow web server. This is the contents of the `.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow webserver daemon
After=network.target
[Service]
Environment=”PATH=/srv/airflow/bin”
Environment=”AIRFLOW_HOME=/srv/airflow”
User=airflow
Group=airflow
Type=simple
ExecStart=/srv/airflow/bin/airflow webserver -p 8080 -- pid /srv/airflow/webserver.pid
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
PrivateTmp=true
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I can start the web server like this:

```
systemctl start airflow-webserver.service
```

However, when I visit the site in a browser, this is what I see:

[image: Cannot Connect]

What could be wrong?

Comment: A few questions: (0) what version of Ubuntu are you running on the server? (1) is Apache installed on the server? (2) are there any errors reported on the screen or in `/var/log/syslog` when you start the service? (3) is `ufw` running? If so, have you configured it to allow traffic on port `8080`?

Comment: You have wrong quotes - replace `”` to normal `"`.